# Cannot click out of off-canvas navigation (bourbon & refills)

Tags: sass, bourbon

I have created an off canvas navigation according to [bourbon's website](http://refills.bourbon.io/components/#er-toc-id-18). I am finding that I cannot click out of the navigation once it's tiled as shown in [this codepen pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByLPob). When the menu is "toggled" I cannot untoggle it.

could it be an issue with `<button>` or with the div afterwords?:

```
<div class="js-menu-screen menu-screen"></div>
```

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I was adding that div within the `<nav>` element in my development environment.

Answer (score -1):

I was adding that div within the  element in my development environment. It should have been outside of the element.